# Using index.jsp in grails

Tags: jsp, grails

I'm trying to switch index.gsp with an index.jsp in a new grails application. I renamed the default index.gsp to not_index.gsp and added the index.jsp. Now I am getting the following error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1229)
```

This is unexpected because the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html) says:

> Grails also supports JSPs as views, so if a GSP isn't found in the
>   expected location but a JSP is, it will be used instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Why? I am trying to convert a very old application (jsp only) to grails and want to see if I can drop the index.jsp in without issues.

Comment: Very you can write almost everything that is written in JSP to a GSP, it's like you can write any Java code in a Groovy code. So it's better rename it to `.gsp`

Comment: Also, if you are using Grails 3, what command you entered to create a new Grails app?

Comment: Why would the documentation say it supports JSP views then? I only did `grails create-app`. Is there another command I should use?

Comment: Not sure, probably it's an older doc because they have not re-written the entire doc from the ground unlike Grails 3

Answer (score 0):

Check your UrlMappings file.
In Grails 3, its at `grails-app/controllers/UrlMappings.groovy`
In Grails 2 its at `grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy`

index is mapped by default with

```
"/"(view:"/index")
```

But since yours is called /index, try adding this to your UrlMappings

```
"/index"(view:"/index")
```

Your index view needs to be in the right location, in Grails 2 mine is located at

```
grails-app/views/index.gsp
```

And I agree, you should try renaming yours .gsp

Comment: I tried "/"(view:"/index.jsp") but that didn't work. I will try this when I get home. I want to move away from jsp but I would like to get the app converted running in grails first. Renaming is a lot more work because there are a lot of include directives and variables that are shared between the includes. Maybe I can put those variables in the request scope to pass them between gsp includes but using jsp would be easier for now.

Comment: On my grails web page, I tried navigating to 'my_grails_url/index' -  this does not work!  But navigating to "my_grails_url/"  does work.  In your UrlMappings, I think you need to add "/index"(view:"/index")  to get 'your_url/index' to work.   You would think your_url/index would be routed by default in UrlMappings, but on my project my testing showed it is not.

Comment: I don't think this works. Are you sure you have a jsp page and not a gsp page?

Comment: Sorry, it does not work when I changed it to index.jsp     I was able to render a index.jsp as a file.  But it was simple html.  It likes you will need to change your .jsp to .gsp and make corrections/changes as necessary to get it working in Grails