# Grails 3.3.9 - Problem displaying JSP in grails 3.3.9 project

Tags: java, jsp, grails

I have a grails 3.3.9 project which includes Java classes and JSP. I have achieved to call a URL and stop in a breakpoint inside my Java class. My Java class is really simple, but the problem comes when I try to display to a JSP:

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
    request.getRequestDispatcher("src/main/resources/es/salenda/test/Entrada.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Given error is 404 but I am not sure if the problem is the URL that I have inserted, the structure where I have saved my files or if there is not possibility to redirect to a JSP.

My directory structure is given below:
[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you want/need your view files defined under `src/main/resources/` instead of `grails-app/views/`?

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown, There is not a valuable reason to have it into this path. But I have changed it inserting the package into views, and having the redirection in this way:     request.getRequestDispatcher("es/salenda/test/Entrada.jsp").forward(request, response);
and the problem goes on.

Comment: Right.  I wouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: You can organize views under `grails-app/views/` however you like.  For example, `grails-app/views/someController/es/salenda/test/Entrada.jsp` is valid.

Comment: Your code is trying to evaluate `src/main/resources/es/salenda/test/Entrada.jsp` at runtime but in your deployment, `src/main/resources/` shouldn't even exist.

Comment: I have put my JSP inside views folder. Even, I have created a simple controller to render a JSP but I have found an error. To check that, I have created a simple project with a controller wich renders a JSP view, which should work according to doc. The result of that is an error similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037676/using-index-jsp-in-grails, which does not contains a correct answer to solve it. I´m still trying to solve it